# Smallest number of edges required to guarantee a 1-factor

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. What is the smallest positive integer for which every graph $G$ of order $n$ and size $m$ contains a 1-factor?

My work: I know that $m \geq \binom{n-1}{2}+1$ as if otherwise you could just form the graph $$G=K_{n-1} \cup K_1$$ which will not contain a 1-factor for all $n$.  Now where i'm confused is showing that all graphs of size at least $\binom{n-1}{2}+1$ actually contain a 1-factor.  If anyone could provide a hint to get me started that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First of all, $n$ must be even.  If $m\geq \binom{n-1}{2}+1$, then the graph has a Hamiltonian path.  From this path, we can find a perfect matching (or a $1$-factor) easily.

Comment: How do we know it's Hamiltonian.  Consider the graph $C_3$ with a vertex connected to any of the vertices.  This graph has size $m=4=\binom{4-1}{2}+1$ but is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: I said "Hamiltonian path," not "Hamiltonian circuit."

Comment: Ahh yes, okay I see now thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph with even vertices and ${n-1}\choose 2$ $+ 1$ edges has a perfect matching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469565/graph-with-even-vertices-and-n-1-choose-2-1-edges-has-a-perfect-matching)